# git commit editor error 'subl -n -w'

Tags: terminal, macos, git

On my ElCapitan, I have vim installed but my git commit is giving errors:

> $ git commit
>   subl -n -w: subl: command not found
>   error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Your default editor is Sublime Text instead of vim. You can change it with this command:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```